# Система скидок в Magento

Tags: cms, magento

Есть два условия для скидок: от трех единиц - 10% и просто 5% на вскидку. Так вот надо что бы считало при заказе 15% в целом,а оно выдает около 14%,то есть Magento сначала высчитывает 10%, а потом уже 5%. Как сделать, чтобы была общая скидка в 15%, а не в 14%?

Comment: у вас округление цены не до целого случаем?

Comment: @Naumov нет,цены по умолчанию уже вбиты без копеек, так сказать

Comment: просто если высчитать сначала 10 процентов а потом 5 то это будет так же что и вычеслить 15процентов сразу. Может цыфры приведёте?

Comment: @Naumov хорошо. например, заказываю три товара по цене 1200 руб. = 3600. сразу в корзине показывает сумму 3240 руб.,то есть сработала скидка на 10%. Ввожу промокод на скидку 5% magento отнимает их от 3240 руб и мы имеем  3078 руб. а мне надо что бы не было по раздельно,а именно эти скидки плюсовались, когда вместе срабатывают...в итоге должно выйти не 3078, а 3060 руб. как то так

Comment: Ну у вас и маркетинг :D это только программно. т.е. взять обсервер на действие когда была оформлена скидка. Получить проценты скидки применёные до этого, сумировать их и вычесть.

Comment: от базовой стоимости естевственно

Comment: @Naumov а можно как-то указать цену за упаковку. то есть в целом указать + что бы фиксированная была?

Comment: Нет, посмотрите лучше на расширения magento платные и бесплатные например https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/discount-conditions-extension-customer-edition.html правда этот платный но всё равно думаю можно найти.